# Variable issues in SSH

Tags: bash, variables, loops, ssh, while-loop

Hey guys I'm trying to run this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p pwd ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -p 11022 admin@$1.test.com<<EOI
i=1
while read line
do
 location="sudo sed -n ${i}p /Users/Shared/$1.txt"
 number="sudo sed -n ${i}p /Users/Shared/$2n.txt"
 my_array=("${my_array[i]}" $line)
 sudo cp /Applications/TEPS\ OS\ X\ Share\ Folder/MAIN\ IMAGES\ FOLDER\ ƒ/${location}${number} /Users/Shared/FYP/$number
 sudo sips -Z 256 /Users/Shared/FYP/$number /Users/Shared/FYP/$number
 ((i++))
done </Users/Shared/$2.txt
exit
EOI
```

basically it reads a text file which gives the location of certain images, and will create a thumbnail of those images, which can be downloaded later. The problem is that I need the value of $i to set the values of $location and $number, but when I set the variable within the while loop the variables are not set. I've tried setting it locally and globally with single quotes, double quotes, passing through with the sshpass, exporting it -This works as a test but $i is of course unknown- tried placing brackets, curly braces, parentheses, escaping $, at this point I have exhausted my ideas, it's probably something incredibly simple, but I could use a fresh pair of eyes, any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
Thanks to Charles Duffy for helping me clean it up so this is what I have now:

```
 #!/bin/bash
        sudo /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p support ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -p 11022 admin@$1.noerrpole.com<<'EOI'
i=1
while read -r line
do
 location=sudo sed -n ${i}p "/Users/Shared/$1.txt"
 number=sudo sed -n ${i}p "/Users/Shared/$2n.txt"
 my_array+=( "$line" )
 sudo cp "/Applications/TEPS\ OS\ X\ Share\ Folder/MAIN\ IMAGES\ FOLDER\ ƒ/${location}${number}" "/Users/Shared/FYP/$number"
 sudo sips -Z 256 "/Users/Shared/FYP/$number" "/Users/Shared/FYP/$number"
 ((i++))
 exit
done <"/Users/Shared/$2.txt"
EOI
```

But now $2 isn't getting passed through to the loop here's what I get back

```
1:bin Photo$ bash -x thumb npco2 20131216154714
+ sudo /usr/local/bin/sshpass -p support ssh -o stricthostkeychecking=no -p 11022 admin@npco2.noerrpole.com
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
SHPA_12-16-2013/
sed: /Users/Shared/n.txt: No such file or directory
cp: /Applications/TEPS OS X Share Folder/MAIN IMAGES FOLDER ƒ/ is a directory (not copied).
Warning: /Users/Shared/FYP/ not a valid file - skipping
Warning: /Users/Shared/FYP/ not a valid file - skipping
Error 4: no file was specified
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool
```

So where $2 should equal 20131216154714 it's returning an empty string like this

`sed: /Users/Shared/n.txt: No such file or directory`

The correct command would be

`sed: /Users/Shared/20131216154714n.txt`

The rest is just failing because $2 isn't passed.
Again thanks for the help!

Comment: ...also, `my_array+=( "$line" )`, if you want to add the individual line (as a single element) to the array.

Comment: ...also, quote your expansions. `<"/Users/Shared/$2.txt"`, for instance, or you'll have bugs whenever the second argument expands to anything other than a single word; `"$number"`, `"$location"`, etc.

Comment: ...also, always use the `-r` argument to read unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise; whenever it's used without `-r`, `read` does processing on its inputs that you probably don't want (expanding backslash-escape sequences).

Comment: I'm confident this will work, thank you very much, the only issue now is that $2 isn't getting passed into the loop. Any ideas? I edited the OP with your suggestions, and updated with results if you want to check it out. Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer appropriately, to demonstrate passing command-line arguments safely across the SSH session.

Comment: Super super duper!!! You have been an enormous help Mr. Duffy, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh ... <<EOI` does expansion on the local end, before starting ssh. Use `ssh ... <<'EOI'` to do expansions on the remote end.

If you want to pass arguments, use `printf '%q '` to quote them so they survive remote unescaping intact:

```
printf -v quoted_args '%q ' "$one" "$two"
ssh user@host "bash -s - ${quoted_args}" <<<'EOI'
   ...
EOI
```